# Decoding/Encoding this "mystery" string

Tags: encryption, character-encoding, hex, encode

I apologize in advanced for the vague nature of this request, I realize it isn't about a specific coding issue (although coding the conversion is my eventual goal). I have a string value that looks like this "Gr3tsgAAAAAAAAAA" and I know that it can somehow be turned into a long integer that looks something like this "3001924890". All of the values I have for the first format end in "AAAAAAAAAA" so that part seems to be consistent.

The part I'm stuck on is I have no idea where to start to make that conversion. Does anyone recognize that encoded string format? Is it some type of hex?

Comment: Try base 64 or 32 but remember that any form or value can be turned into an integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'AAA...' represents zero bytes in Base64 encoding. If all of your values end in 'AAAAAAAAAA', then they are likely all four-byte values, with trailing zeroes. For example, 'Gr3tsgAAAAAAAAAA' Base64-decodes to the byte array [26, 189, 237, 178, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]. Combining the first four bytes into a four-byte integer, you have to choose between Big-endian or Little-endian, i.e. in which direction do you read the bytes? It could be (26 * 256 * 256 * 256) + (189 * 256 * 256) + (237 * 256) + 178, or it could be 26 + (189 * 256) + (237 * 256 * 256) + (178 * 256 * 256 * 256). So I would guess this represents 448654770 or 3001924890. You can try that and see if it gives expected results. I would expect it to be little-endian, where in this example, 26 is just 26, and the number builds up to the right (giving 3001924890) which would let the extra places to the right build up to bigger numbers if needed.

Comment: Yes. This was exactly correct. It was Little-endain. One of the first things I attempted before posting was trying to use the built in .FromBase64String but it never worked. However, with your answer I was able to manually create that function myself. Thank you very much for your knowledgeable answer on such a "bad" question.